# Unable to download package: Could not find package ... in feed

Tags: octopus-deploy

I set up Octopus for the first time to try how it works. So far I installed the Octopus server, the tentacle and configured NuGet as a local feed. I published a package using OctoPack, created a release and I'm trying to deploy it to staging.

On the first step I get an error The package could not be downloaded from NuGet. 
ERROR Unable to download package: Could not find package Web 1.0.0.0 in feed: '\solomon\deednugetfeed\' System.Exception: Could not find package Web 1.0.0.0 in feed: '\solomon\deednugetfeed\'

Well, the package is there, the NuGet repository test succeeds.

The portal, Octopus service and the NuGet feed are running on Win2008 machine. At first the Octopus server was using the default Local System account, the portal the default ApplicationPoolIdentity (the portal has its own pool). While trying to deploy I got the error listed above. Then, I created a new local account, added it to the Administrators group and set both the octopus service and the app pool to run using the new account. The NuGet folder is shared with the new account. Unfortunately that didn't have any effect (all services are restarted).

Do you have any clue what I could be missing?

Thanks!

Comment: Is the package there in the RSS feed? Any exceptions in the system logs? Have you tried it with an administrator password just to see if the problem is permissions based?

Comment: Do you have the deploy step configured to use the correct NuGet server?  Octopus ships with an internal server and supports external ones.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using octopack, you should use octopus built in nuget feed for your nuget package step. The other options will be slower for you.

The following msbuild parameters are working with octopack successfully. You need an octopus api user and api key.

Command line arguments:

```
/t:Rebuild /p:AutoParameterizationWebConfigConnectionStrings=False /p:DebugSymbols=false /p:DebugType=None /p:IsAutoBuild=True /p:CreatePackageOnPublish=true /p:Configuration=Release;DeployOnBuild=True;PackageLocation=".\obj\Release\Myproject.zip";PackageAsSingleFile=True /p:RunOctoPack=true /p:OctoPackPackageVersion=%VERSION%-dev /p:OctoPackPublishPackageToHttp=http://octopus.yourdomain.com/nuget/packages /p:OctoPackPublishApiKey=API-xxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

After that you should deploy it with deploy.cmd, which is coming with msbuild. You should add a deploy.ps1 to your csproj. Just call myproject.deploy.cmd in the powershell script. Remember that you must name your nuspec file with the same name as your csproj file. Octopus automatically deploys your files which are your content propertied sln files.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change download option to "Octopus Server will download the package, then securely upload it to the Tentacles" in the process step where the nuget is downloaded. It seems that octopus tentacle can't reach the nuget feed.